# How to open a url in new window without toolbar, menubar

Tags: javascript, html

here i am trying to open a URL in new window using window.open

I have a list of anchor tags with some URL, When i click on those anchor tags the javascript should get the href="" value and pass the value to the javascript function.

Here is code what i have done:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
var a;
    function popitup(a)
    {
        window.open(a,
        'open_window',
        'menubar=no, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, dependent, width=800, height=620, left=0, top=0')
    }
</script>
<body>
<form name="popup" >
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" onclick="popitup(this.value)">yahoo</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="popitup(this.value)">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.msn.com" onclick="popitup(this.value)">MSN</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click the yahoo, the www.yahoo.com should get opened in new window.. Similarly all

but now when i click on those links i am getting the error "server not found" in the new window.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the following issues

1. spaces in parms
2. most browsers will ignore the status=no and more - scrollbars for example
3. you follow the link even if you open the window - return false or as I show, false if the popup did the job, true if not
4. no need for form. Links are not form elements and do not have value but href

IF you do not have a popup blocker AND you do not have "open new windows in tabs" THEN this code may work in your browser. If there is a popup blocker, the link still works

```js
function popitup(link) {
  var w = window.open(link.href,
    link.target || "_blank",
 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,dependent,width=800,height=620,left=0,top=0');
  return w ? false : true; // allow the link to work if popup is blocked
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com" onclick="return popitup(this)">yahoo</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com" onclick="return popitup(this)">Google</a>
<a href="https://www.msn.com" onclick="return popitup(this)" target="MSN">MSN</a>
```

These parms are what I would use

```
'resizable,width=800,height=620,left=0,top=0'
```

Comment: live demo not exist

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Now it does

Comment: So save it to your server and allow pop-ups! The code does what it is allowed to do, as designed

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Would you mind not voting a 7 year old post down before you have a conversation about if this script will work or not for you in 2020?

Answer (score 2):

You `this.href` instead of `this.value` in your `onclick` handlers. The `href` attribute of an anchor tag is not its value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
var a;
    function popitup(a)
    {
        window.open(a,
        'open_window',
        'menubar=no, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, dependent, width=800, height=620, left=0, top=0')
    }
</script>
<body>
<form name="popup" >
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" onclick="popitup(this.href)">yahoo</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="popitup(this.href))">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.msn.com" onclick="popitup(this.href))">MSN</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w7y9K/)

Comment: this will pop AND follow the link too

Answer (score 1):

lastest update with ES6 Javascript based on mplungjan Solution

```js
document.addEventListener("click", navigateTo, false);
function navigateTo(event){
  if (event.target.matches('a')) {
      window.open(event.target.href,"_blank",'menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,dependent,width=800,height=620,left=0,top=0');
 }
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
you need run this locale to check Code Snippet not allow Popups<br>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.msn.com">MSN</a>
</body>
</html>
```